Associated Prime ideals of an ideal in a ring
I know associated prime ideal of $R$-module $M$ is prime ideal $P$ in $R$ such that $P = \text{ann}_R (x)$
and associated prime ideal of an ideal $I$ in a ring $A$ is a prime ideal $P$ such that there exits an $a +I \in A/I$ and
$P = \text{ann}_A (a+I) = ( I :_A a )$.
But from $1$'st uniqueness theorem of primary decompositions ( Theorem $4.5$ in Atiyah MacDonald) associated prime ideals in an ideal $I$ of a ring $A$ precisely the prime ideals of the form  $\sqrt{( I: a )}$ for  $a \in A$
Then by the above two definition of associated primes of an ideal $I$ in a ring $A$   we have $\text{Ass} (A/I) =\text{Spec} A \cap \{\sqrt{( I : a )} : a \in A \} = \text{Spec}  A \cap \{ (I : a) : a \in A \}$
Is it a true statement ? Since prime ideals are radical ideals  then $\text{Spec} A \cap \{\sqrt{( I : a )} : a \in A \} \supseteq \text{Spec} A \cap \{ (I : a ) : a \in A \}$ What about the other inclusion ? Is it true always or is it true only for noetherian rings ?  If yes, why ?
[Note : Here all rings are commutative rings with multiplicative identity and ideals are decomposable ]

The definition of associated prime of an ideal you gave is true when $R$ is Noetherian (see Atiyah-MacD Proposition~ 7.17). But the first uniqueness theorem doesn't assume $R$ to be Noetherian. So this makes the confusion. See the definition Atiyah-MacD provided for non-Noetherian ring.

What is the actual definition of an associated prime ideal of a R- module M where R is need NOT to be a noetherian ring ?

See the paragraph in Atiyah-MacD above proposition~4.6. That gives definition of associated prime of an ideal of $ R $. For module I think similar notion exists and one can define in similar way but I personally have studied for the Noetherian case only which follows your definition!!
